# How to re-encode the content read from DataMatrix?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, datamatrix

I tried to interpret the DataMatrix code and read the following,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDnu.png)
0000  05 01 ff ff 00 00 30 36  32 53 ee 87 9e 00 0a 1b  | ~~~~~~062S~~~~~~ |
0010  93 87 01 d4 1c 00 e2 3d  34 01 81 48 01 00 da de  | ~~~~~~~=4~~H~~~~ |
0020  9b 00 00 00 04 00 02 00  00 5c fc 47 00 37 37 30  | ~~~~~~~~~~G~770 |
0030  30 07 be 06 2f 5b bb b2  c4 e3 9f 79 92 61 9a 22  | 0~~~/[~~~~~y~a~" |
0040  78 0c a9 c7 3c 6d 55 2f  fc 7b 05 ca af 79 bb f9  | x~~~<mU/~{~~~y~~ |
0050  5f bb 38 14 54 41 80 5a  38 09 05 4f b9 2f 05     | _~8~TA~Z8~~O~/~  |

But when I re-encode the content back to the DataMatrix QR code, the scanned content is not the same as the above content. Is there any way to re-encode it into the same original DataMatrix QR code?

Comment: What is the Datamatrix code and the Datamatrix QR code and what is the difference? Then did you encode the first Data matrix code? If so, was the data you specified for encoding the same as the data notified by the barcode reader? Was the data specified in the encoding for creating the second Data matrix QR code the same as the data notified by reading it with a barcode reader? It will be difficult to give advice or answers unless you provide all the details of what you have done, the data and programs you used for it, and the results.

Comment: Correct it. It is DataMatrix. I want to know what code can be used to encode a datamatrix?

Comment: To get advice and answers, you need to add details of each step and result of the process, not just comments. Please update the question article.